# Google Cloud Vision - Is there a way to automatically decide between using DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION and TEXT_DETECTION?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I am looking for a way to call Google as few times as possible so I am wondering if there is a way for Google to automatically decide weather to use `TEXT_DETECTION` or `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` through **Python Cloud Vision** client?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for this, since the [client](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/vision/gapic/v1/api.html) uses different methods for each type.

You can fill a feature request regarding this scenario on the following [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=0) if you consider this would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Vision API has no way to determine which is the "best" detection method to use -- this is for you to decide.